# What exactly is the history of Dynamic Time Warping? Where can I find information?

Tags: history, dynamic-time-warping

I am writing a thesis comparing some methods of time series classification, part of which is DTW combined with K-NN algorithm. I'd love to know (and write, backed by reliable references) something about the history of this algorithm, but I can't gather up information.

Searching through publications I wrote down first that (1) it was first introduced in 1975 and applied to speech recognition, then in 1994 someone proposed use in time series in general (unfortunately I don't remember where does this info come from, probably 1994 part is from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/216301292_Everything_you_know_about_dynamic_time_warping_is_wrong) because this is 2004 paper and it says that A decade ago, DTW was introduced into Data Mining community as a utility for various tasks for time series problems including classification, clustering, and anomaly detection."). I think that somewhere I read also that (2) DTW is known since 1960's, but [this paper](https://ralphniels.eu/pubs/niels-dtw.pdf) about DTW states that (3) "In the year 1983, Joseph Kruskal and Mark Liberman introduced a new technique to compare two
curves (calculate the distance between them)".

I can't make sense of information I have and don't know where to find more and make sure that everything is correct and consistent. I can't afford spending much time on research about history, because other thesis parts are far more important. What can I do? Does anyone know a good (and preferably just one) source of information about DTW history?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful
http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/KruskalLiberman1983.pdf

The paper that introduced DTW to data mining/AI/ML was [a]

You will also find this very useful
https://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/techreports/2008/08-04/08-04.pdf

eamonn

[a] Berndt, D. & Clifford, J. (1994) Using dynamic time warping to find patterns in time series. AAAI-94 Workshop on Knowledge Discovery in Databases (KDD-94), Seattle,
Washington.